# QGIS, Print Composer's legend regresses to old style classes

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I'm using QGIS 2.16 to create some rather simple vector maps.
However, ever since I made some modifications to the style of one layer (e.g. I added one more class) the Print Composer regresses and gives me the old style classes as soon as I deselect the `Auto update` function. I already tried reinstalling the software (I had run 2.15 before) and saving/loading the new layer style, but to no avail.
Any advice on this?

Comment: Could you share screenshots - or even better a screencast - of the situation to help us understand / reproduce the issue?

Comment: I could have, sorry for the delay. Eventually, I ended up starting the task from scratch and the error did not reoccur.